# Sturm-Liouville Problem --Suppose that the functions $p(x), p′(x), q(x)$, and $r(x)$ in $[p(x)y′]′ − q(x)y + \lambda r(x)y = 0, \quad (a < x < b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that the functions $p(x), p′(x), q(x)$, and $r(x)$ in $[p(x)y′]′ − q(x)y + \lambda r(x)y = 0, \quad (a < x < b)$. Question pasted as image given below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have 3 cases:

1-) $\lambda=0$

The solution is $y=c_1+c_2x$, applying boundary conditions, $c_1=c_2=0$ hence $y=0$

2-) $\lambda<0$

The solution is $y=c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda} x}$, applying boundary conditions, $c_1=c_2=0$ hence $y=0$

3-) $\lambda>0$

The solution is $y=A\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+B\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x}$. Applying $y'(0)=0$ we obtain $A=0$, applying $y(L)=0$ we obtain $B\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} L}=0$. If $B=0$ we obtain trivial solution. So $\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} L}=0$, which implies $\sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{n\pi}{2L},n=1,3,5,...$

Therefore eigenvalues are $\lambda=(\frac{n\pi}{2L})^2$ and corresponding eigenfunctions are $y_n=B_n\cos\frac{n\pi}{2L}x$

Comment: $y'(0)=0$ will make B= 0, since sin(o) =0 which will kill A.

Comment: $$y(x)=A\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+B\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x}\Rightarrow y'(x)=\sqrt{\lambda} (A\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x}-B\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x})\Rightarrow y'(0)=0\Rightarrow\sqrt{\lambda} (A\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} 0}-B\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} 0})=0\Rightarrow A\lambda=0 \Rightarrow A=0$$

Comment: I think its supposed to be written like this:                                 $y(x)=A\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+B\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x}\Rightarrow y'(x)=\sqrt{\lambda} (-A\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+B\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x})\Rightarrow y'(0)=0$

Comment: @Avinesh: In the answer the general solution is founded as $y(x)=A\sin{\sqrt{\lambda} x}+B\cos{\sqrt{\lambda} x}$. If you consider this as solution you get $A=0$. On the other hand if you take the solution as in your comment then $B=0$.

Comment: So you say both ways its correct.

Comment: Yes, just the names of constants changed.